# tableau apply filter to only one of the measures

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Tableau workbook which has 3 measures m1,m2 and m3.
Those are aggregated by year and summed, so I end up with a table like this:

---

```
|     |     2017        |     2018     |
----------------------------------------
| m1  |      10        |      20       |
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
| m2  |      10        |      20       |
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
| m3  |      10        |      20       |
----------------------------------------
```

However, I have to apply a date filter to variable `m3` so that the resulting table will look exactly like the one above, but in the background m3 data is filtered.

I would like to be able to do something like:

`if metric == m3 then filter(year)`

Does anyone know how to achieve this in Tableau?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [Level of Detail Expressions](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html).

Create a calculated field for m1 and m2 measures, as follows:

```
{FIXED [Year]: SUM(m1)}
```

This will make all filters other than `Year` don't have any effect on this measure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't think this is working. If I create a calculated field `m1_calc`, as per your example, values are different respect to m1 without filters.

Comment: It actually worked with `{FIXED: SUM([M1])}`. Without using [Year]. If you change your answer I will accept it.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
if metric == m3 and year=2017
then sales
end
```